# Accessing WordPress posts externally from another domain

Tags: php, wordpress, external, posts

Is it possible to access & process WordPress posts of domain1.com by running a php script on domain2.com.  I want to access posts of domain1.com and store information like title, permalink, tag into a database on domain2.com

I do have admin access over domain1.com but for some reasons i want to access it thru domain2.com

Any help to give me a starting point would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with the Rest API https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ Though this would work better for live accessing the data rather than storing it to the DB as you'd have to do a lot more work to store / update the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access your domain1.com posts from domain2.com very easily using either **XML-RPC API** or **REST API**. But REST API will be more convenient as you won't have to work with any XML parsing. REST API is robust, easy and future-proof and it will give you JSON data which is pretty easy to work with.

Here is the REST API doc:
http://v2.wp-api.org/
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

And here is the XML-RPC if you are wondering:
https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API